# Taskbar icon appears blank (possibily due to a sticky cache)

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi

I am having some issues with invalidating the Windows icon cache. I'm running a Win32 app that used to show the taskbar icon properly, however, after replacing the app's icon, the taskbar icon appears blank. It's interesting because when I use ALT-TAB, the correct icon does show up.

The window is created with `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`. I know it registers the correct icon because after pinning/unpinning it from the taskbar, the icon shows up as expected. I’ve gone through several attempts to solve this and have narrowed it down to refreshing the icon cache.

A few of the ways I tried to reset the icon cache:

- Delete all icon cache files in folder:
  `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Microsoft/Windows/Explorer/`, and restart `explorer.exe`
- In Command Prompt: `$ie4uinit.exe -show`
- Using Shell APIs to force the taskbar to refresh (`SHChangeNotify`)

[image: Blank Taskbar icon]

Having gone through several different attempts and configuration techniques, the taskbar icon remains blank as shown above. I was wondering if there is another foolproof technique for resetting the Windows icon cache.

Comment: Restart the machine

Comment: It's a bug in Windows, has always been there, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did try to restart, more than once. It didn't help.

Comment: @JonathanPotter do you know if it has it been reported or referenced somewhere?

Comment: Are you setting the icon via `NOTIFYICONDATA`? Can you show you us the code?

Comment: @Omer restarting the system clears the icon cache. Probably you've not restarted the system or the cause of your bug isn't caching of icons. Since you didnt show any code nobody can help you. You need to learn how to debug and isolate the problem. Guesswork and speculation seldom proves useful.